# PHP inserting date format into input's "placeholder"

Tags: php, placeholder

Within my PHP code I have a form in which one of its' input boxed should be inserted as date format. I would like to instruct the user to assign the date in a particular format. That instruction is given via HTML5's "placeholder".
I did this:

```
<input id="exam_date" name="exam_date" type="datetime" placeholder="<?php echo now('d-m-y H:i:s'); ?>">
```

But instead of present date format I get:

```
"now('d-m-y H:i:s')"
```

I wanted to show real date / time of inserting the time !
How can I use "placeholder" to show present date time?

Comment: Try date instead of now --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP there is no `now` function. Use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) instead.

```
<input id="exam_date" name="exam_date" type="datetime" placeholder="<?php echo date('d-m-y H:i:s'); ?>">
```

Comment: If the server had no php installed you would see `<?php ... ?>` as placeholder... That's why that answer was bad and I replaced it with the correct one. But this would not solve the issue why the OP sees `"now('d-m-y H:i:s')"`, because if the server supports PHP you would see a PHP syntax error instead.